# Dependency version from configuration file

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have a maven project in which I need to read some dependency version from some configuration file instead of hardcoding it in the pom. How to achieve that?

Comment: Why using a configuration file which is hardcoding in another taste just use the pom file...I hope you define fix versions in your pom file otherwise your build is not reproducible.

Comment: I intend to build different variants of the product from same line of code. Variant is provided as environment variable and for each version there is a separate config file.That way build is still reproducible for given variant.

Comment: @kathdroid AFAIK this cannot be done. You can define versions as command line parameters, but not through a file.

Comment: Does this configuration file control any flow within your code?

Comment: BTW : An environment variable is not reproducible cause if you build on a different environment it will not work anymore ...why do you need different variants in particular dependencies?

Comment: Maven build is just a part of a more general build workflow which uses configuration files to have all variant dependent properties in one place. Whole build environment is under version control and it cannot change freely. Environment variable that decide about variant is injected by Jenkins build job which is also under version control. The variable is used to activate maven profiles where there are differences. I also need to use different online help jar and API jars from remote repository depending on the current variant.